# Monad Transformers. First step

Tags: haskell

Let's consider:

```
type Name   =  String                -- variable names

data Exp    =  Lit Integer           -- expressions
            |  Var Name
            |  Plus Exp Exp
            |  Abs Name Exp
            |  App Exp Exp
            deriving (Show)

data Value  =  IntVal Integer        -- values
            |  FunVal Env Name Exp
            deriving (Show)

type Env    =  Map.Map Name Value    -- mapping from names to values

eval0 :: Env -> Exp -> Value
eval0 env (Var n) = fromJust (Map.lookup n env )
```

And above is 0 version.

Now, let's consider monadic, 1 version:

```
type Eval1 a = Identity a
eval1 :: Env -> Exp -> Eval1 Value
eval1 env (Var n)  =  Map.lookup n env
```

And now, the author said:

> The next is that the Var case does not need a fromJust call anymore:
>   The reason is that Map.lookup is defined to work within any monad by
>   simply calling the monad’s fail function – this fits nicely with our
>   monadic formulation here. (The fail function of the Maybe monad
>   returns Nothing, whereas the fail function in the Identity monad
>   throws an exception, which will lead to different error messages.)

The content comes from: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf
and it is not clear for me. Please explain why introducing monad Eval1 allow us to don't care about `fromJust`.

EDIT:

Now, I tried to compile it and I got error and this error is consistent with my intuition and my doubts. The compiler says:

```
Couldn't match type `Maybe Value' with `Identity Value'
Expected type: Eval1 Value
  Actual type: Maybe Value
In the return type of a call of `Map.lookup'
In the expression: Map.lookup n env
In an equation for `eval1': eval1 env (Var n) = Map.lookup n env
```

So, who is right, author or compiler and how to repair it?

Comment: I believe the author was right some time ago, where `lookup` used to return `m a` for any monad `m`. Now, `lookup` only returns `Maybe a`.

Comment: When I was reading this paper a few weeks ago, I had the same question. I did find an updated version of the paper (or at least the code) that fixed this; I'll see if I can dig up the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time that draft was written, `Data.Map.lookup` apparently did work with any monad. This is no longer true, but the author does provide an [updated version](https://github.com/mgrabmueller/TransformersStepByStep/blob/master/Transformers.lhs) of the tutorial.

Specifically, you have to examine the resulting `Maybe String` value and call `fail` explicitly.

```
-- Copied from the link above
eval1 env (Var n) = maybe (fail ("undefined variable: " ++ n)) return $ Map.lookup n env
```

Answer (score 2):

> The reason is that Map.lookup is defined to work within any monad by simply  calling the monad's fail function

It's not true. In the text the definition of `Map.lookup` is different from the real definition in `containers` package. The author generalized `Map.lookup` to any monadic value, not only `Maybe`:

```
lookup' :: (Ord k, Monad m) => k -> Map k a -> m a 
lookup' k m = case Map.lookup k m of
    Nothing -> fail "some_error_message"
    Just v  -> return v
```